# How to create a Python executable with nix flake

Tags: python, nix, nix-flake

I have a directory with two files, *main.py* and *flake.nix*.

*flake.nix*:

```
{
  description = "virtual environment with python and streamlit";
  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        python = pkgs.python311;
        python_packages = python.withPackages(ps: with ps;[
          ipython
          matplotlib
          pandas

        ]);


        myDevTools = [
          python_packages
        ];
      in {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = myDevTools;
        };
      });
}
```

What should I use in *flake.nix* in order to create an executable that is equivalent to the following?

```
    python main.py
```

I want to create the executable with the command

```
    nix build
```

in the shell (it means with the necessary packages installed)

I have added apps in my file:

```
{
  description = "virtual environment with python and streamlit";
  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        python = pkgs.python311;
        f = ps: with ps;[
          ipython
          matplotlib
          pandas
        ];
        pip_python_packages = python.withPackages(f);

        myDevTools = [
          pip_python_packages
          pkgs.streamlit
        ];
        outputName = builtins.attrNames self.outputs self.outputs;
      in {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = myDevTools;
        };

        packages.default = pkgs.poetry2nix.mkPoetryApplication {
          projectDir = self;
        };
        apps.default = {
          program = "${python}/bin/python";
          args = [ "main.py" ];
          src = "./.";
          type = "app";
      };

      });
}
```

But nix runs only to open the python interpreter.

Furthermore, I enter this line

```
    nix/store/cxsw4x1189ppmsydhwsmssr0x65nygj7-python3-3.11.4/bin/python ./main.py
```

in my shell

because ${python} = cxsw4x1189ppmsydhwsmssr0x65nygj7-python3-3.11.4/bin/python

And it didn't work:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I changed my file like this:

```
{
  description = "virtual environment with python and streamlit";
  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }: flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
    let
      pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
      python = pkgs.python311;
      f = ps: with ps;[
        ipython
        matplotlib
        pandas
      ];
      pip_python_packages = python.withPackages(f);

      myDevTools = [
        pip_python_packages
        pkgs.streamlit
      ];
      outputName = builtins.attrNames self.outputs self.outputs;
    in {
      devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
        buildInputs = myDevTools;
      };

      packages.default = pkgs.poetry2nix.mkPoetryApplication {
        projectDir = self;
      };

      apps.default = flake-utils.lib.mkApp {
        program = "${pip_python_packages}/bin/python";
        args = [ "${self}/main.py" ];
      };
    });
}
```

But I have this error now after running `nix run`:

> error:
> … while evaluating the attribute 'pkgs.buildPythonPackage'
>
> ```
>      at /nix/store/s1z7nb9n6r5n0r34fabp6yybwkbr8mjk-source/pkgs/development/interpreters/python/passthrufun.nix:87:5:
>
>        86|     withPackages = import ./with-packages.nix { inherit buildEnv pythonPackages;};
>        87|     pkgs = pythonPackages;
>          |     ^
>        88|     interpreter = "${self}/bin/${executable}";
>
>    … while calling the 'mapAttrs' builtin
>
>      at /nix/store/s1z7nb9n6r5n0r34fabp6yybwkbr8mjk-source/pkgs/development/interpreters/python/passthrufun.nix:31:8:
>
>        30|           value;
>        31|     in lib.mapAttrs func items;
>          |        ^
>        32|   in ensurePythonModules (callPackage
>
>    (stack trace truncated; use '--show-trace' to show the full trace)
>
>    error: getting status of '/nix/store/c274sjvcr30c80429v9kpn4n2q0ic6n9-source/poetry.lock': No
> ```
>
> such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but maybe this helps.

Quite a lot of things are wrong here.

> But nix runs only to open the python interpreter.

Yes - `args` means nothing here so is ignored. [Only `type` and `program` mean anything](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/new-cli/nix3-run.html#apps).

> And it didn't work:
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

This is because `python` is just that - the Python runtime. Your libraries are in their own derivations, so inaccessible from that derivation.

If you're using poetry2nix then you should lean on *that* more. See [their template flake](https://github.com/nix-community/poetry2nix/blob/master/templates/app/flake.nix).

As you didn't include a `pyproject.toml` it's hard to recreate your setup, but by adding those packages with:

```
poetry add ipython streamlit matplotlib
```

You can then try something a bit more like this (note that poetry2nix now warns against using the nixpkgs version):

```
{
  description = "virtual environment with python and streamlit";
  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

  inputs = {
    poetry2nix = {
      url = "github:nix-community/poetry2nix";
      inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
    };
  };
  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, poetry2nix }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        inherit (poetry2nix.lib.mkPoetry2Nix { inherit pkgs; }) mkPoetryApplication;

      in {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          inputsFrom = [ self.packages.${system}.default ];
        };

        packages.default = mkPoetryApplication {
          projectDir = self;
        };
      }
    );
}
```